# Identify this power series / solve this trig equation

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, closed-form, power-series

I was asked to find a solution to
$$\frac{\sin^2(nx)}{n^2\sin^2(x)}=2^{-1/2}$$
where $n$ is a fixed integer greater than 1.

Numerically, there's a solution just above 1/n so I decided to find this one (rather than one of the other roots).  I hoped to find an obvious pattern that I could use to find some sort of closed-form solution.

It turns out that the power series of the root jumps out, numerically.  Since x is only used inside a sine, the power series has only odd terms.  The coefficients look like

1.0019063576966069771401037205331682344703361047262779848987578751140847/n +

0.466422280109844953629560577622677335783739044717/n^3 +

0.3247444758314010835749/n^5 + ...

which are annoyingly close to 1, 1/2, 1/3, ... but are clearly distinct.

Any idea how to solve this?  This is, I'm sure, well beyond anything the original question-asker cares about, but now my interest is piqued.

Comment: Let me nit-pick a little bit: what you wrote is not a *trig identity* but a *trigonometric equation*.

Comment: The power series of what, exactly?

Comment: @Hans: The power series of the (specified) root of the equation.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now that it's written as a series in $n$ it's clear.

Comment: My mistake -- I was writing it on paper with different variables and I mistranslated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the $x=\arccos\;y$ substitution suggested by Mariano suffices; what you will then have will be the equation $\left(\frac{U_{n-1}(y)}{n}\right)^2=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ where $U_n(y)$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\arccos y$, replace the $\sin^2$ in the numerator by $1-\cos^2$, and use the trigonometric definition of [Chebyshev's polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) to transform the equation into a polynomial equation on $y$. Then solve that using any of the usual ways to solve it (numerically!)